# How to write a very large json into kafka using python

Tags: python, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I have a JSON of 4.6 GB size with the following structure:

```
[
  {...},
  {...},
  ...
]
```

I want a python code to read this JSON and write them into a Kafka topic with 16 partitions as much as possible.

One challenge is reading this large JSON without exhausting the memory. (using splitting and generators comes to mind as viable solutions). And, maximizing the producers' efficiency is the second challenge.

I've tried several solutions but can't get past 15MB/S of writing. [I'm using `python-kafka` library which is not the most performant python library for kafka]

Comment: Kafka has a default maximum message size of 1MB. How are you getting passed this?

Comment: Several days ago, I had a bench test for massive traffic. The kafka cluster has 5 brokers on c5.4xlarge AWS ec2 instance and producer/consumer on c5.xlarge instance. My result is max throughput from 1 producer/consumer is around 12MB/s wirte and 30MB/s read. When I use c5.2xlarge for producer/consumer, throughput is around 15MB/s write. So if the kafka cluster has enough capacity, I think it much more depends on producers computing power, network bandwidth and producers configurations. I used ksql-datagen for testing producer.